# Writing phenaki video to file: Expected numpy array with ndim `3` but got `4`

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, generative, pyav

I'm trying to write the output of the Phenaki make_video to an mp4 file. I'm using this Phenaki implementation from github https://github.com/lucidrains/phenaki-pytorch/search?q=make_video

```
phenaki = Phenaki(
    cvivit = cvivit,
    maskgit = maskgit
)


entire_video, scenes = make_video(phenaki, texts = [
    'blah blah',
], num_frames = (17, 14, 14), prime_lengths = (5, 5))

entire_video.shape # (1, 3, 17 + 14 + 14 = 45, 256, 256)
torchvision.io.write_video(filename= "test.mp4", video_array= entire_video, fps=24)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
  File "/.../GitHub/phenaki-pytorch/run.py", line 49, in <module>
    torchvision.io.write_video(filename= "test.mp4", video_array= entire_video, fps=24)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 132, in write_video
    frame = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format="rgb24")
  File "av/video/frame.pyx", line 408, in av.video.frame.VideoFrame.from_ndarray
  File "av/utils.pyx", line 72, in av.utils.check_ndarray
ValueError: Expected numpy array with ndim `3` but got `4`
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the numpy array expected to be 3 dimensions for av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray?

Answer (score 0):

According to [write_video](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.io.write_video.html) documentation, `video_array` argument format is "tensor containing the individual frames, as a uint8 tensor in [T, H, W, C] format".

The dimensions of `entire_video` is (1, 3, 45, 256, 128), so there are 5 dimensions instead of 4 dimensions.
The exception says ndim `3` but got `4` (not 4 and 5) because the dimensions mismatch is detected in an internal loop.

The order of the dimensions is also wrong (`3` applies number of color channels, should be the last dimension).
The type of `entire_video` is also wrong - the type is `float32` instead of `uint8`.
Assuming the `entire_video` resides in the GPU memory, we also have to copy the tensor to the CPU memory before using `write_video`.

---

Before using `write_video`, we may apply the following stages:

- Copy the video from the GPU memory to CPU memory (and remove redundant axis):

  ```
   entire_video = entire_video[0].detach().cpu()
  ```
- Convert from `float32` to `uint8` applying offset and scale.
  The following code uses global minimum and maximum (the conversion is not optimal - used as example):

  ```
   min_val = entire_video.min()
   max_val = entire_video.max()
   entire_video_as_uint8 = ((entire_video - min_val) * 255/(max_val min_val)).to(torch.uint8)
  ```
- Reorder the axes to be ordered as [T, H, W, C]:

  - First axis applies frame index (shape value is 45 when there are 45 video frames).
  - Second axis applies row index (shape value is 256 when there are 256 rows in each frame).
  - Third axis applies column index (shape value is 128 when there are 128 columns in each frame).
  - Fourth axis applies applies color channel (shape value is 3, because there are 3 color channels - red, green and blue).

    ```
      vid_arr = torch.permute(entire_video_as_uint8, (1, 2, 3, 0))
    ```

---

Complete code sample:

```
import torch
from phenaki_pytorch import CViViT, MaskGit, Phenaki
from phenaki_pytorch import make_video
import torchvision

maskgit = MaskGit(
    num_tokens = 5000,
    max_seq_len = 1024,
    dim = 512,
    dim_context = 768,
    depth = 6,
)

cvivit = CViViT(
    dim = 512,
    codebook_size = 5000,
    image_size = (256, 128),  # video with rectangular screen allowed
    patch_size = 32,
    temporal_patch_size = 2,
    spatial_depth = 4,
    temporal_depth = 4,
    dim_head = 64,
    heads = 8
)

phenaki = Phenaki(
    cvivit = cvivit,
    maskgit = maskgit
).cuda()

entire_video, scenes = make_video(phenaki, texts = [
    'blah blah'
], num_frames=(45, 14, 14), prime_lengths=(5, 5))

print(entire_video.shape)  # (1, 3, 45, 256, 128)

# Copy the video from the GPU memory to CPU memory.
# Apply entire_video[0] for removing redundant axis.
entire_video = entire_video[0].detach().cpu()  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754525/4926757

# Convert from float32 to uint8, use global minimum and global maximum - this is not the best solution
min_val = entire_video.min()
max_val = entire_video.max()
entire_video_as_uint8 = ((entire_video - min_val) * 255/(max_val-min_val)).to(torch.uint8)

# https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.io.write_video.html
# video_array - (Tensor[T, H, W, C]) – tensor containing the individual frames, as a uint8 tensor in [T, H, W, C] format
# https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html
vid_arr = torch.permute(entire_video_as_uint8, (1, 2, 3, 0))  # Reorder the axes to be ordered as [T, H, W, C]


print(vid_arr.shape)  # (45, 3, 256, 128)
torchvision.io.write_video(filename="test.mp4", video_array=vid_arr, fps=24)
```

---

After all that, the created video file looks like random noise...

[image]

It looks like this is the output of `make_video` and not related to the subject of the post.